# Would like to play wav-file using chunks of byte-arrays instead of play()

Tags: c#, wav, audio-player

I cannot find a way to play wav-files "chunk-wise", meaning playing byte chunk(`byte[]`) to byte chunk.

Between the comments in the code, I have a made-up method called `playSound(byte[], int firstInde, in stopIndex)`.

 I wonder if there is a method in some class that is similar to that one that can handle "chunk-wise" audio playing.

```
byte[] b = null;
int chunkSize = 512; 
int chunkIndex=0;
int fileSize=512000;
try{
    using (var steam = Properties.Resources.sju_tre_g_i)
    {
        steam.Read(b,0,fileSize);
    }

    while(chunkIndex < b.Length)
    {
        //-------------The method I would like to use------
        playAudio(b, chunkIndex, chunkSize);
        //-------------------------------------------------

        chunkIndex += chunkSize;
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, you're also missing some chunks..

Comment: Hi. I changed the code a bit to make it work better. But the thing I am looking for is  a way to stream the sound chunk by chunk in a whileloop until the bytearray b is empty. And not with a player that play the whole stream at once.

Comment: Check out `RawSourceWaveStream` from [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio). [Here is an example](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RawSourceWaveStream.md).